# Convert record of numbers to record of strings

Tags: typescript

Suppose you have a simple map:

```
const nums = {
  100: 2,
  200: 4,
  300: 8,
  400: 16,
} as const;
```

And you want to create a new object that has a 1:1 correspondence to that `nums` object, but the keys are a string variation of the numbers:

```
const pixels = {
  100: '2px',
  200: '4px',
  300: '8px',
  400: '16px',
} as const;
```

This new `pixels` construct must meet these requirements:

- It has only the keys in `nums`
- It has only the values in `nums`
- The value for key `X` must be `Xpx`.

So far, I have managed a solution that meets all but the last requirement:

```
const spacingInt = {
  100: 2,
  200: 4,
  300: 8,
}

type SpacingInt = typeof spacingInt;
type SpacingKey = keyof SpacingInt;
type SpacingValue = SpacingInt[SpacingKey];
type SpacingValuePx = `${SpacingValue}px`;
type SpacingMap = Record<SpacingKey, SpacingValuePx>;

export const spacingStrings = {
  100: '2px',
  200: '4px',
  300: '8px',
} as const satisfies SpacingMap;
```

In the code above, `spacingStrings` must have exactly the keys [100, 200, 300]. The values of those keys must be '2px', '4px', or '8px'. However, I wish to ensure, for example, that `spacingStrings[300]` is always of type `8px` and not merely of type `'2px' | '4px' | '8px'`. Unfortunately, the code above allows the following without triggering an error:

```
export const spacingStrings = {
  100: '8px',
  200: '2px',
  300: '2px',
} as const satisfies SpacingMap;
```

I suspect that the answer requires inference or another advanced TS feature that I'm unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a matter of declaring a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
const nums = {
  100: 2,
  200: 4,
  300: 8,
  400: 16,
} as const;

const strings: { [K in keyof typeof nums]: `${typeof nums[K]}px` } = {
  100: '2px',
  200: '4px',
  300: '8px',
  400: '16px',
};

const x = strings[100]; // inferred as '2px'
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=15&ssc=45&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCuBbCMC8MDeBYAUDGAjAAxEBcMATADS74UnkAsNeMAzAzABwv6OcEAbCwC+MAIYpQkKAG5cuadBjQATgEswAcwjkMMANoBpGJpgBrAKYBPEADMYUawAdL9uEggBdcgAMAJBhOru4IyMZeIs4AHr4wYujYrMRkMADkFDFpvJScaYxZORypaVyFtDD8JULlOCLyOIrgytFoKlAa2hAGKV6yMAD0A6ZgdpaqqpYAJhIoGVlAA)</sup>

---

You could easily create the above `strings` object automatically using a combination of `Object.fromEntries()`, `Object.entries()` and `map()` but would likely need an explicit cast as `Object.entries()` is fairly loosely typed.

Also note that numeric object keys are always converted to strings.

Comment: Brilliant. My mistake was in using `Record` instead of a literal `{ ... }`. I see the subtle difference now. Thank you!